# Is there any way to do multiple inheritance in Ext js v3.4

Tags: javascript, extjs, multiple-inheritance

In my application there is a single select dropdown (ComboBox)

Now I want to add check box to every text in that dropdown ( to make it multi-select)

Im aware that there is a [plugin](http://lovcombo.extjs.eu/) to get this done but I wonder if its possible with multiple inheritance(i.e create a new element by combing dropdown and checkbox) ?